# C++, Convert string to int

Tags: c++

I`ve tried many ways to convent a string to a int. This includes atoi() and stringstream 
But i still cannot convert it. I have a only numeric string and i want to convert it to a int.

The reason for that is that im receiving data form user using **getch()** and storing it into a string buffer, but in a certain point i want to convert this buffer to a int for use.
So my string would be like that:

```
string hello = "673";
```

And i want to transform this value into an interger.
**EDIT**
This is not a duplicated questions because i tried
all this methods many times and still now work.All of this just crash my program or error an invalid conversion.

Comment: And what exactly was wrong with `int n = atoi(hello.c_str());`?

Comment: it crashes my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this :-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

int main(void) {
int value;
std::string str("12345");

std::istringstream ss(str);
ss >> value;
std::cout<<value<<std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

atoi() should work. Check if your string has non numeric characters in the front or somewhere in it. Could you show us the exact string you are trying to convert into int?

Comment: Just created a string and used push_back() to insert numerical chars into it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a c++ style string try stoi() instead of atoi(). It plays nicer with the C++ string class.